# Facebook share button not working (popup)

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I am trying to make a custom Facebook share button with a popup. I am using this code:

```
function fbs_click(width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
    u=location.href;
    t=document.title;
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
}
```

and for the link:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=www.stackoverflow.com" onClick="return fbs_click(400, 300)" target="_blank" title="Share This on Facebook"><img src="fblogo2.png" alt="facebook share"></a>
```

It creates the Facebook popup, but for some reason it won't use the link I'm supplying. Could someone give me some pointers to what I might be doing wrong please?

Comment: Is it using `www.stackoverflow.com` instead? That would mean your JS code has not worked correctly, and only the “normal” link action was executed. And btw., trying to pass the title as parameter doesn’t work any more, Facebook will take that information from the shared link itself instead.